# Beam: Sharing state between two streams

Tags: stream, streaming, apache-flink, apache-beam

I was wondering if there was a way to share state between two PCollection with apache beam.

To give you a little more context, I have two PCollection. The first one is a stream of songs. The second one is a stream of the form `genre=boolean`. (Ex: rock=false, pop=true). I want my output PCollection to only have the song with the genre that are true.

I know that in apache flink you can do this by using the connect function and then processing the two streams at once with RichCoFlatMapFunction. Is there anything similar in Beam or another way to do this?

I look into side inputs a little bit but from what I understand these require bounded streams and I am not sure if the state will be persisted outside the window.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me exactly what you mean by a stream here but I'll assume these are data streams that are available to a Beam pipeline through a supported data source such as Cloud Pub/Sub or Kafka. If so, in Beam terms, these will be two unbound input `PCollection`s.

In this case, Beam offers multiple ways to combine/join the two `PCollection`s.

- One way would be to use one stream as a main input to a Beam ParDo step while using other stream as a [side input](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs). You will be doing your joining within the `ParDo` step and possibly follow by other steps (`GroupByKey`, `Combine`, etc.) to do further processing on the output stream and write it out using a Beam sink (for example, to Kafka, BQ, GCS, etc.)
- Another way would be to use the Beam's built in [CoGroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey) transform to automatically combine the two `PCollection`s based on keys.
- Also look into [Beam SQL](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/overview/), which might make this kind of joining much easier.

Comment: Yes I meant PCollection! Thank for the input